# Installing RMagick Error on windows 7 to create image with Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rmagick

Hello Guys 
now i found this video to installing  RMagick on windows 7 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEWAVlNCKhg

by using this steps 
1- install ImageMagick static on the directory C:/ImageMagick 
2- install ImageMagick dll on the same directory C:/ImageMagick 
3- Extract the ImageMagick-6.8.8-2.tar on the same directory C:/ImageMagick  and rename the folder to "SourceCode" 
4- install  mingw on the directory C:/MinGW 
5- add the path (C:/MinGW) to my windows Environment Variables

After making  all the steps  when i try to run the command 
 `gem install rmagick` 

OR

```
gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="C:/ImageMagick"'
```

it gave me this Error ??
why I always got this error ???????
how i can solve this issue ????

note : also i followed the steps in this article 
http://rubylearning.com/blog/how-do-i-install-a-ruby-gem-with-native-extensions-on-windows/ 
to fixed **gem native extension** but still got the same error

> 

Error : Failed to build gem native extension.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.
  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.
  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:172:in `` `': Invalid argument - convert -version (Errno::EINVAL)
    from extconf.rb:172:in ``'

Answer (score 1):

Guy 
finaly i got the true method to install it on windows 7

1- install ImageMagick-6.7.9-0-Q16-windows-static.exe  in the path C:/ImageMagic 
2- install ImageMagick-6.7.9-0-Q16-windows-dll.exe  in the path C:/ImageMagic  
3- Extract the ImageMagick-6.8.8-2.tar in folder and rename it to SourceCode then set it in the path C:/ImageMagic/SourceCode
4- install mingw-get-setup.exe in the path C:/MinGW 
5- define the Environment Variables  for the user 
PATH - C:\MinGW\bin;

6- used the command (gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="C:/ImageMagick"')
7 - open Gemfile and set (gem 'rmagick')
8 - type the command (bundle-install)

you can follow this article 
 
https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki

the error happen to me because i was installed the ImageMagick  version 6.8